# Компиляция java в geany

Tags: geany, ide, java

Как прописать настройки компиляции, сборки и запуска java-проекта в geany?

Comment: Лучше eclipse, если geany не можешь настроить =)

Comment: Мне нужно выполнить приложение во внешнем терминале. В Geany это я могу сделать. Правда в качестве параметров прописал именно абсолютный путь к каждому файлу, то есть привязано чисто к моему проекту. А вот в eclipse и netbeans я не нашел способов запуска консольных приложений во внешнем терминале.

Comment: В зависимости от того, что нужно сделать, можно в eclipse экспортировать все в jar, затем запустить из командной строки `java -jar my.jar`

Comment: Да, конечно, если не смог настроить geany, то 100% надо на eclipse :D

По сабжу - ну в настройках же, там все элементарно. Вместо абсолютных путей, там, где они не нужны используйте "переменные":

    "%f" - полное имя файла
    "%e" - имя файла без расширения
    "%d" - полный путь к корневой директории

Comment: @AlexWindHope, ага, лошара я, в глаза не видел Geany.

Comment: @Dex, уважаемый, вы знаете что такое **сарказм**?

Добавлю еще что мой комментарий, кагБэ, адресовался не Вам

Comment: @AlexWindHope, да, я знаю, что такое сарказм, именно в русле сарказма и был мой предыдущий ответ, вот тут мне стоит, правда, извиниться, ну не привыкши я использовать смайлы. Но, даже при таком раскладе, не считал ваши слова сарказмом и мне интересно будет, при наличии времени, взглянуть на этого зверя.

Answer (score 1):

Допустим есть директория, где лежат файлы с исходниками и скомпилированные классы.
Для примера **/home/user/workspace**. В подкаталоге **src** лежат исходники в соответсвующих пакетах. В каталоге **bin** скомпилированные классы. В Geany устанавливаем команды сборки следующим образом:

```
Команда компиляции: javac -sourcepath ./src -d bin %d/%f
Рабочий каталог:    /home/user/workspace
```

**echo %d/ | cut -d'/' -f 5-** выдаёт относительный путь к компилируемому файлу. Для другого пути нужно будет подправить параметр -f (man cut)

По такому же принципу исполнение:

```
Команда выполнения: java -classpath ./bin `echo %d | cut -d'/' -f 6-`.%e
Рабочий каталог:    /home/user/workspace
```

Comment: А зачем ```echo %d/ | cut -d'/' -f 5-```, если можно по идее просто `%d`?

Comment: просто %d вернёт полный путь, а нужен относительный, чтобы корректно прописались пути к пакетам

Answer (score 0):

Команда выполнения: java -classpath ./bin `echo %d | cut -d'/' -f 6-`.%e
ТОЧКА ПЕРЕД %e похоже лишняя. в остальном всё робит спасибо